# How to delay page until DOM manipulation has been completed?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a very minimal teaser page with a counter written in pure Javascript (no jQuery etc.).

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Countdown:</h1>
  <p id="counter"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 01, 2019 10:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var countdownfunction = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time, calculate distance
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownfunction);
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
```

It works pretty well. However, when the page loads, it starts with an empty line and about a second later, the countdown is displayed.

Is there a way to avoid that behavior? I'd like to show the countdown right from the start, even if this means to delay the display of the whole page until the DOM is ready.

At the moment, the JS-code is located in an external file. I load this file at the end of the `<body>`. I also placed it ant the end of the `<head>` with no difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just call the function that populates the counter immediately?

Comment: Were did you place this line of code? in `window.onload` function? in an external javascript file included in the page? beginning/end of the page?

Comment: I updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your Javascript is loaded after your HTML is loaded. Put your code into the `<head>` section:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m ";
    };
</script>
```

... it needs window.onload too (thanks to Kaddath).

Comment: Thanks. I updated my original post again. How would you integrate the `window.onload` in that code?

Comment: Just put all your code in the scope of the window.onload = function { ... }

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't work: `window.onload = function() {
    var countDownDate = ;
    var countdownfunction = setInterval(function() {...} }, 1000);
}`